# SQLite does not order by two columns

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE stopsbuses (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, stop_id NUMERIC, bus_id NUMERIC, drive TEXT, day TEXT);
CREATE TABLE stopsbusestimes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sb_id NUMERIC, timeh NUMERIC, timem NUMERIC);
```

When I execute query like this:

```
SELECT timeh, timem FROM stopsbuses 
INNER JOIN stopsbusestimes ON stopsbuses._id = stopsbusestimes.sb_id 
WHERE stopsbuses.stop_id = 2 ORDER BY timeh asc, timem asc
```

Output for example is:

```
[..]
7 1
7 31
7 34
7 54
7 57
7 22
[..]
```

Same output is with simple:

```
SELECT timeh, timem FROM stopsbusestimes ORDER BY timeh, timem
```

Same output using php + pdo, SQLite Database Browser and in Android aplication.

Am i missing something in ordering by two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, all strings are sorted behind all numbers, so it's likely that `22` is not a number.

To see the types, try [`typeof`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof) or [`quote`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#quote):

```
SELECT quote(timeh), quote(timem) FROM stopsbuses ...
```

Comment: Yes, it turns out that some timem instances are text, not integer. But how it is even possible if in table creation it is timem NUMERIC. Thanks, I will take a look at the import of data.